# How to read data from all files in a directory using C Language?

Tags: c, file-io, io

I am trying to 1) Find all files in a directory and display them, 2) Open all found files and read data from them (characters) 3) Output the read data to the screen or a new file.

This is done in C Language and you will see below my current code. The problem that I am running into is that: I can find all the files in my directory and print them to the screen just fine (point 1 above), but when I try to open the found files and read data (characters) from them (point 2 above), I get a segmentation fault.

If I comment out the `fscanf(entry_file, "%s", files);` line below, but leave the `entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");` line, it compiles okay and writes the files to the screen. I also tried indexing the `fscanf` line with the `int i` (not shown below) and produced the same segmentation fault.

So, how can I read data from these found files? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    DIR* dir;
    FILE *entry_file;
    struct dirent *in_file;
    char files[1000];
    int i;

    dir = opendir("/Users/tcn/data");

    if(dir==NULL){
        printf("Error! Unable to read directory");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( (in_file=readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        printf("%s\n", in_file->d_name);
        entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");

        fscanf(entry_file, "%s", files); 
    }

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(entry_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but you should close your `entry_file` inside the loop.

Comment: `entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");` need check return value.(maybe need full path of file) also need `fclose` each file.

Comment: `files` can only hold `1000` bytes, maybe one or more of your file has more than that? Also, you are opening all files and not closing them. Theres a limit of how many files you can have open simultaneously. Also, check that the opening of the file was successful, and, if I'm not mistaken, `in_file->d_name` is just the base name of the file, you have to append `/Users/tcn/data/` to the beginning of it's name to pass it to `fopen()` otherwise `fopen()` won't find the file. You can use `chdir()` to workaround the need to do that (you only need to call it once).

Comment: You should check `entry_file` for `NULL` before using it, and `fclose` it afterwards if it wasn't `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two most likely causes of the crash are not checking the return value of `fopen` – then either the `fscanf` or the `fclose` may crash when attempting to use `entry_file` when it's `NULL` – and the potential overflow of `files`.

Another problem which does not cause a crash is that the `in_file->d_name` does not contain the full path, but only the name of the file. So if you are testing the code inside `/Users/tcn/data` then it will appear to work, but it will fail elsewhere. Either prefix the filename with `/Users/tcn/data/` or operate only on the current directory (`.`).

Fixes:

```
if ((entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r"))) {
    (void) printf("%s\n", in_file->d_name);
    if (fgets(files, sizeof files, entry_file)) { // or `while`?
        // do something with `files`, it will be overwritten for next file
    }
    (void) fclose(entry_file);
}
```

And remove the other `fclose(entry_file)` from the end of the code.

Also note that if you use this code with an arbitrary directory, it might contain pipes and/or device nodes that will hang forever when you attempt to read them.

Comment: Why the `(void)` before `printf`? (Just curious)

Comment: @moffeltje Casting an unused return value to `(void)` indicates that it is intentionally discarded rather than accidentally left unassigned (`printf`, too, does return a value, though it is seldom used). It's a coding style I've apparently become so accustomed to that I didn't realise I did it here until you pointed it out… =) Some lints and compiler options can also enable warnings for unused return values, and the `(void)` cast silences them.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you are correctly checking for `NULL` against `dir` and `in_file` before using them, the only other thing that could possibly be causing this is `entry_file` being null. Check it before using it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    DIR* dir;
    FILE *entry_file;
    struct dirent *in_file;
    char files[1000];
    int i;

    dir = opendir("/Users/tcn/data");

    if(dir==NULL) {
        printf("Error! Unable to read directory");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((in_file=readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        printf("%s\n", in_file->d_name);
        entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");
        if (entry_file != NULL) {
            fscanf(entry_file, "%s", files);
            /* whatever you want to do with files */
            fclose(entry_file);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that, as multiple other users have commented, you should close `entry_file` *within* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function with a loop using `fread()` to replace the `fscanf` line, and do a hex dump. For one thing, you don't know if the files are text files or binary files. For another, the segfault could be coming from reading a binary file that contains no `newline` into `char files[1000];` And even if the files *are* all text files, you cannot predict that your "generous" 1000 length is enough to hold the first line of text.